# Can i change the time between notification emails for customer APS Updates?

Tags: notifications, centos6, plesk, aps

I'm running a dedicated server and i like that my customers receive these updates from plesk 12,

But they receive an email every day.

Is there any way to make it so that they only get updates once a month?

I know i can disable/enable them via "Tools & Settings - Notifications" but i want to change the regularity of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

APS updates notifications are sent as a part of Daily Maintenance task so it is not possible to modify the period.